# DSE Search - nodetool cleanup fails with syntax error

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I added a new node to my DSE Search cluster and tried to run `nodetool cleanup` after both nodes were up and joined to the cluster. However I get an error. Here's the top of the stack trace. Any ideas what caused this error? I don't know where to begin to repair this. Corrupt core?

```
Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:8,1,main]
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
  org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'brand_id_internal:7333
  AND event_type:CB AND category_id: AND specific_id:E': Encountered " 
  <AND> "AND "" at line 1, column 58.
Was expecting one of:
  <BAREOPER> ...
  "(" ...
  "*" ...
  <QUOTED> ...
  <TERM> ...
  <PREFIXTERM> ...
  <WILDTERM> ...
  <REGEXPTERM> ...
  "[" ...
  "{" ...
  <LPARAMS> ...
  <NUMBER> ...
```

The remainder of the stack trace is in a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/tightly-clutched/d963d31b7954bae96b2adf0f9bdd10dd)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SyntaxError string, I found the solr core that was causing the problem. I unloaded the core using `dsetool unload_core main.mycf_name` and then was able to run `nodetool cleanup` without problem.

I recreated the core `dsetool create_core main.mycf_name`; I tested `nodetool cleanup` and it still worked.